# ASP.Net RadioButton loses ViewState

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate, radio-button

I'm having trouble with a simple radio set of two radio buttons (I don't want to use a RadioButtonList [RBL] because RBL doesn't allow child controls, and in my case, if you select one option, I want to enable a textbox next to the button; yes you could hack this with jQuery to move the textbox, but that's dirty!). I would check one, submit the form (either explicitly or through AutoPostBack), and the CheckedChanged event would never fire. When the page was reloaded, both buttons would be unchecked, regardless of their initial state on non-postback load or the state before form submission.

I took out the checkbox and stripped this down to the simplest example I could come up with. I tossed EnableViewState=true all over the place just in case it was being disabled somewhere I couldn't find.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">
    <div>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="foo" Text="foo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbChanged" Checked="true" GroupName="foobar" EnableViewState="true" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="bar" Text="bar" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="foobar"
            OnCheckedChanged="rbChanged" Checked="false" EnableViewState="true" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="resultLbl" />
    </div>
</form>

protected void rbChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (foo.Checked) resultLbl.Text = "foo is checked";
    else if (bar.Checked) resultLbl.Text = "bar is checked";
    else resultLbl.Text = "neither is checked";
}
```

Comment: the code you posted should work, but I'm not sure If I understood well what it's not working for you. Could you try to explain it better?

Comment: File under FWIW, when I add a pair of checkboxes with similar behavior to the page; they work correctly. If I inspect foo or bar during PageLoad with VS' immediate window, foo is checked when it's not a postback, otherwise neither is ever checked.

Comment: The code does not work -- the result label never has any text and the CheckedChanged event (rbChanged) never fires.

Comment: You may want to try deleting your page and recreating it. Perhaps between debugging and file locks, the designer file has become messed up. As my answer states below, I tested your `exact` code in a fresh aspx page and it works fine. When you select either radio button, the page posts back and updates the label.

Comment: Maybe something in page_load is resetting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was because we had a custom adapter rendering the HTML for a radiobutton (or to be precise, for all System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox es). Our motivation for this was because .NET will put a disabled="disabled" attribute on the LABEL and the input, which is bad HTML, and worse, is actually interpreted to mean something by IE! (Check it out for yourselves -- write up an HTML page with a label disabled="disabled" and test in FF and IE.)

We used Reflector to see what step we were mixing up vs what the real adapter did, and found that the Name attribute was being set incorrectly. Although it set all the RBs in a given group to the same Name, it was not the same Name attribute in our limited new-solution test case as it was in our custom-adapter test case. When we looked at how to generate that safely, we found that our postbacks suddenly worked!

If we get permission from the boss, we'll contribute our adapter to CSSFriendly in case anyone else has use for this sort of thing.

Comment: Interesting problem and solution. For what it's worth - I've used the CSSFriendly adapters in the past and run into more minor issues than I can think of. Sometimes having the 'perfect' html really is overrated. In the end a usable site to the end user is key. They could care less about valid html. It's a balancing act between pretty markup and development time IMHO. Often ensuring completely valid and 'best-practice' html with generated markup frameworks like ASP.NET is more trouble than it's worth. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: The only problem was that IE was 'dimming' the label that was disabled too. As in fading it to light gray like a disabled form control. This was basically impossible to read on some background colors, and we didn't want to say "well we can't use that background color because we can't control the HTML" because that's lousy. :)

Still haven't gotten all the kinks worked out -- it doesn't generate the correct group if you have a naming container to consider. MS has too many internal methods!

Comment: I think the problem is that any disabled controls will lose the viewstate

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your exact code and it works fine. When you select either radio button, the lable is updated during postback and correct information is shown when the page refreshes??

Comment: Hm. I'll see if I copy the page into a new solution if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the issue may be caused by `ScriptManager` in code-behind.

**For e.g.**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "DisplayMessage", "javascript: HideProcessingImage();", true);
```

Using the same key name in different methods as above may be the issue of radio button autopostback not working.
I've faced this issue so anyone with same issue can solve their problem.