# ASP.NET checkbox losing value on postback due to JavaScript/jQuery array?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, checkbox

I have a simple `asp:RadioButtonList` within a `form` tag but for some reason it isn't keeping it's value on postback

Here's what I've got

```
<form runat="server">   
<div class="Form">
<span class="FirstField">        
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="radiolist1" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>        
</span>
</div>
</form>
```

At the moment all I'm trying to do is get it to keep it's value on postback - it works in Safari but not in Firefox or Internet Explorer.

Any ideas?

**Edit**:

I've just found out that it is something to do with my javascript in the head of my page

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var originalValues = new Array();   
    $("input").focus(function() {     
        if (!originalValues[this.id]) {
          originalValues[this.id] = $(this).val()
        }           
        if ( $(this).val()==originalValues[this.id]) {
               $(this).val('').css({'color': "#000", 'font-style': 'normal'});
        }  

        $(this).css({'background-color':'#E8E8E8' });    
       });

    $("input").blur(function() {
       if ( $(this).attr("value")=="") {
           $(this).val(originalValues[this.id]).css({'color': "#666", 'font-style': 'normal', 'font-weight': 'normal'});
       }   

       $(this).css({'background-color':'#fff' });      
    });
});
```

Comment: Have a look at the update of my answer. You should exclude `input type=radio` from this jQuery-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have some other input elements on your page which use this javascript.

Try specifying the type of input you want the javascript to run on:

```
$("input:text").focus(function() {
```

replace :text with the type you're using.

Comment: Thanks Tom just what I was after

Answer (score 0):

Is ViewState enabled for page and control?

- EnableViewState property for the page is set to true.
- EnableViewState property for the control is set to true.
- ViewStateMode property for the control is set to Enabled or inherits the Enabled setting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstate.aspx

**EDIT**: you don't need to save the old "text" on a RadioButton (html=`input type=radio`), so you have to apply this function only on textboxes etc. I'm not so 
familiar with jQuery, but you should be able to do this with a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/). Maybe with the [:not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)/function:

[untested]

```
$("input").not(input[type=radio]).focus(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

I have pasted your code in a newly created ASP.NET website and was able to retrieve the `SelectedValue` and `SelectedIndex` properties.
Are you using a custom adapter for rendering HTML? Please take a look at: [ASP.Net RadioButton loses ViewState](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2632660/337294)